# Conditional Aurelia Validation on Visibility of Element

Tags: validation, typescript, aurelia

I'm trying to work out some license subscription form with aurelia and aurelia validation plugin.
I have a fieldset for personal information where most of them are required and get validated by aurelia validation.

Now I also have a fieldset for credit card information and for billing address with also fields that are required and validated. The thing is, they only get displayed when the user picks the subscription radio button.
I have all the required fields in the ValidationRules, how can I tell aurelia that it should only validate the ones that are currently visible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use conditional validation with the `when` fluent method. Here is an example from the [Aurelia Docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/2).

`ValidationRules
  .ensure('email')
    .email()
    .required()
      .when(order => order.shipmentNotifications)
      .withMessage('Email is required when shipment notifications have been requested.');`

Answer (score 2):

If you use if.bind on your element, the hidden element will not get validated.

Unless you want the element in your DOM but only hidden, use if.bind.
That way, your element is not rendered in dom, so not validated.

show.bind -> hide/show element

if.bind -> render/not render element